# Hide button inside the ListView

Tags: c#, wpf

I have got a `ListView` and each row has a `Button`. I want to hide Buttons until the user selects any row.

I used in my ViewModel :

```
 private Visibility _deleteButtonVisibility;
 public Visibility DeleteButtonVisibility { get { return _deleteButtonVisibility; } set { _deleteButtonVisibility = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DeleteButtonVisibility)); } }
```

In my Constructor

```
 DeleteBtnVisibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

XAML code i used this

```
 <GridViewColumn Width="100">
      <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate >
              <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                  <Button Click="DeleteBand_Click" Visibility="{Binding DeleteBtnVisibility }" Content="Delete" Width="88"></Button>
              </StackPanel>
          </DataTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      <GridViewColumn.Header>
          <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="Delete" >Delete</GridViewColumnHeader>
      </GridViewColumn.Header>
  </GridViewColumn>
```

ViewModel event listener:

```
    private void WarningModel_OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.PropertyName == nameof(SelectedWarning))
        {
            if(SelectedWarning != null)
            {
                DeleteBtnVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
    }
```

binding is not working inside the `ListView`. 
If i use the same binding any other objects outside of the `ListView`, it hides the object. 
I tried to hide `<StackPanel>` which contains the `Button` but still no success. 
I am not sure why Binding doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried a trigger to set the visibility of the button based on the `ListItem.IsSelected` property?  I'd expect this to be possible purely in XAML, without any code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `DeleteBtnVisibility` property is defined in the view model of the `ListView` (or its parent view), you could bind to it using a `RelativeSource`:

```
<Button Click="DeleteBand_Click"
        Visibility="{Binding DataContext.DeleteBtnVisibility, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" 
        Content="Delete" Width="88" />
```

Comment: Yes, it is working... Thank you. But why? I don't understand the reason behind.

Comment: Your original binding fails because the `DataContext` of the `Button` in the `GridView` is the corresponding item in the `ListView` and not the view model.

Comment: Thanks for all your help